# message validation throws "No Message Found" exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, hl7, hl7-dotnetcore

I'm using the hl7-dotnetcore package to create new HL7 messages. After creating them I want to serialize some of them to strings and some of them to bytes. I created an empty .NET Core console project with the following snippet

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Message mdmMessage = new Message();

        mdmMessage.AddSegmentMSH(
            "sendingApplication",
            "sendingFacility",
            "receivingApplication",
            "receivingFacility",
            string.Empty,
            "MDM^T02",
            $"Id{DateTime.Now.Ticks}",
            "P",
            "2.6");

        HL7Encoding hl7Encoding = new HL7Encoding();

        //################################
        // Add a field e.g. TXA.1

        Segment txaSegment = new Segment("TXA", hl7Encoding);
        txaSegment.AddNewField("1", 1);
        mdmMessage.AddNewSegment(txaSegment);

        //################################
        // Add a component field e.g. PID.5.1

        Segment pidSegment = new Segment("PID", hl7Encoding);
        Field patientNameField = new Field(hl7Encoding);
        Component pidFamilyNameComponent = new Component("Doe", hl7Encoding);
        patientNameField.AddNewComponent(pidFamilyNameComponent, 1);
        pidSegment.AddNewField(patientNameField, 5);
        mdmMessage.AddNewSegment(pidSegment);

        try
        {
            string messageString = mdmMessage.SerializeMessage(true); // This will throw an exception
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Serialization failed:{Environment.NewLine}{exception.Message}");
        }

        try
        {
            byte[] messageBytes = mdmMessage.GetMLLP(true); // This will throw an exception
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Conversion failed:{Environment.NewLine}{exception.Message}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get two exceptions with

> "Failed to validate the message with error - No Message Found"

Does someone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Just pass `false` instead of `true` to `SerializeMessage` and `GetMLLP`. They accept argument called `validateMessage`, and by that they mean validating raw message you passed to constructor of `Message` or by setting `HL7Message` property. Since you did neither of that - there is nothing to validate, and when you try to - it complains about invalid (empty) message. It's quite arguable design, but it is what it is.

Comment: @Evk thanks for your reply. Ok so this boolean is only relevant when assigning something to the `HL7Message` property?

Comment: Yes, you can see how it works in source code: https://github.com/Efferent-Health/HL7-dotnetcore/blob/master/src/Message.cs#L699

Comment: You can also see an example of creating new message from the authors of the library on main library page (https://github.com/Efferent-Health/HL7-dotnetcore), section "Remove Trailing Components". You might notice they also use `message.SerializeMessage(false);` at the end.

Comment: hmm yeah ... If you want to you can create an answer so I can reward you the bounty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `Message.SerializeMessage` and `Message.GetMLLP` accept boolean argument `validateMessage` which behaves in a bit weird way: if true then *original* message, that is message you passed to the constructor of `Message` or set via `HL7Message` property, is being validated. Since you do not have original message but building a new one (without using mentioned property or constructor) - there is nothing to validate, and empty message is treated as invalid, so you see the error. So just pass `false` to avoid this unnecessary in your case validation:

```
string messageString = mdmMessage.SerializeMessage(false);

byte[] messageBytes = mdmMessage.GetMLLP(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Message` object expects to have some value for `HL7Message` and without that it throws this error as your can see from [the source](https://github.com/Efferent-Health/HL7-dotnetcore/blob/d71debe7e64035e4c9c85b9455948ab173cdbe6c/src/Message.cs#L827) here.

Update your code to add some message string as below:

```
string sampleORM = @"MSH|^~\&|Organization||ALLINA||20170331171205||ORM^O01|3149|P|2.3||||NE
PID|1|42311|42311|42311|Jane^Doe^T||19921112|M|||123 Worth Drive^^Troy^OH^45373^^Home||9373328660^Phone^Home^^^937^3338660|||||42311|111223333|||^Unknown^CDCREC
PV1|1|1|^^^^^^^^Oak Ridge Big Name Location||||^Smith (M)^Michael|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||20170331
ORC|NW|11777-60|||||^^^20170331||20170331171150|||^Smith (M)^Michael|^^^^^^^^Oak Ridge Big Name Location||20170331
OBR|1|11777-60||4241^BRAZIL NUT (F18) IGE - 86003^AllinaCodes||20170331171150|20170331|||||||||^Smith (M)^Michael|||||||||||^^^201703311200"; // some HL7 message

Message mdmMessage = new Message(sampleORM);
```

and it should take care of the error.

Comment: I want to create new messages, I don't want to parse existing ones